# Angularfire2 - Query table with a param

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am trying to retrieve all the items that have a param with a certain key.

Here is the function that fills an array with the retrieved items:

```
    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
     (param: any) => {
    let postId = param['id'];
    console.log(postId);
      this.postsService.subscribePostReplies(postId)
             .do(console.log)
            .subscribe(posts => { this.posts = posts; this.cdr.detectChanges(); });
     });
```

Here is the method within the service:

```
 subscribePostReplies(postKey: string) {
    return this.af.database.list('posts', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'repliedTo',
            equalTo: postKey
        }
    });
 }
```

Problem is the page refreshes when the query happens and I also get alerted with:
     FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "repliedTo" at /posts to your security rules for better performance

Answer (score 1):

Your warning pretty much spells it out.

> WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "repliedTo" at /posts to your security rules for better performance

`".indexOn": "repliedTo"` @ `/posts` will looks something like this:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,

    "posts": {
      ".indexOn": "repliedTo"
    }
  }
}
```

Remember, this is just a warning and indexOn is not required for development.

> Indexes are not required for development unless you are using the REST API. The realtime client libraries can execute ad-hoc queries without specifying indexes. Performance will degrade as the data you query grows, so it is important to add indexes before you launch your app if you anticipate querying a large set of data.

Comment: I'm getting this warning, too. My database rules correctly specify the `.indexOn`, as you've described here.
The warning disappears if you remove the `equalTo`.

Comment: Not sure why you would remove `equalTo`, as that is the entire point of the query that @Pete was trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh, I don't want to remove `equalTo` - it's essential, of course. It's just that the warning disappears if you do.

However, I've solved my problem properly, now. I hadn't published the the rule changes (local JSON file) back up to Firebase. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Just add .indexOn Rule as described in the firebase documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data